# authorize wheel group to rm in specific folder

Tags: sudo, directory, rm

I would like to authorize wheel group to rm in a specific folder (in this case my folder is "CT").

I've tried to add this line in visudo:

```
%wheel All=(ALL) /bin/rm /CT/
```

I have a test files "test1" in CT folder and when I try to rm with wheel user, I get the message that I'm not authorized to run `/bin/rm test1`

Comment: I would like to allow rm * for all CT folder. There won't be sub folders, only files. Thx for your help

Comment: I was just testing but in the end there will be only files. My bad.

Comment: I didn't know I had to be this specific in sudoer file. I've just edited my question. Thx for your advices

Comment: You don't have to be this specific. But if you're only going to delete files why let people delete directories too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to remove files from the `/CT` directory itself, this could be done without any reference to `sudo`.

Initially you need to set the group ownership and permissions as root:

```
chgrp wheel /CT
chmod g+rwx /CT
```

Now users in the `wheel` group have permission to (create and) delete any files in this directory without using `sudo`:

```
rm -f /CT/unwanted.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Your command allows wheel group users to run `rm /CT/`. Nothing more. Nothing less.

You could try this, which will allow users to remove `/CT/` and anything inside it provided they use the exact same flags as specified here:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) /bin/rm -rf /CT/*
```

My general preference for `sudo` control is to write a script that validates the arguments, and have that script permitted through `sudo`. Perhaps something like this might suffice, which checks that the target is a file inside the folder `/CT`

```
#!/bin/bash
#
ss=0
for item in "$@"
do
    real=$(readlink "$item")
    if [[ "$real" =~ ^/CT/. ]] && [[ -f "$real" ]]
    then
        rm -f -- "$item"
    else
        [[ -t 2 ]] && echo "Refusing to remove '$item'" >&2
        ss=1
    fi
done
exit $ss
```

You can add other conditions to require the target to be a directory, to have particular ownership, etc.